# Read and append each nth row from csv files in a folder python

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, csv

I have a folder containing 30 files, each of them containing thousands of rows. I would like to loop through the files, creating a dataframe containing each 10th row from each file. The resulting dataframe would contain rows 10, 20, 30, 40, etc. from the first file; rows 10, 20, 30, 40, etc. from the second file and so on.

For the moment I have:

```
all_files = glob.glob("DK_Frequency/*.csv")
li = []
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)
```

that appends in a list the different files from the folder. But I don't know how to go further.

Any idea? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will slice the `df` with every 10th row using `iloc` and then append it to the `final-df`. At the end of the loop, the `final_df` should contain all the necessary rows

```
all_files = glob.glob("DK_Frequency/*.csv")
li = []
final_df = pd.DataFrame()
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    final_df.append(df.iloc[::10])
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I receive the error:    
pandas.io.common.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file

Comment: Can you specify where this error originates from? My guess is there is a problem with the csv files being read

Comment: ..."/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 730, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 923, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1390, in __init__
    self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 538, in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas/parser.c:5902)
pandas.io.common.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file

Answer (score 1):

Pandas read_csv allows to keep only every 10th line with `skiprows`. So you could use:

```
all_files = glob.glob("DK_Frequency/*.csv")
li = []
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0, skiprows = lambda x: 0 != x%10)
    li.append(df)
global_df = pd.concat(li, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all the csv files have the same structure, you could do as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
all_files = glob.glob("DK_Frequency/*.csv")

#cols_to_take is the list of column headers
cols_to_take = pd.read_csv(all_files[0]).columns

## create an empty dataframe
big_df = pd.DataFrame(col_to_take)

for csv in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(csv)
    indices = list(filter(lambda x: x % 10 == 0, df.index))
    df = df.loc[indices].reset_index()

    ## append df to big_df
    big_df = big_df.append(df, ignore_index=True)
```